# Misalignment in grid system with sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I'm creating a grid system on a page layout by following the [**documentation**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

My layout causes misalignment when using a grid system with sidebar. The two `<div>` inside the row are not aligned and appears with a page break. I've playing with `col` and `offset` values with no success.

[**DEMO in Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/9QqTBHgfci)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
                <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
                <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>

                <div class="row placeholders">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
                        <img data-src="holder.js/200x200/auto/sky" class="img-responsive" alt="200x200" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyMDAiIGhlaWdodD0iMjAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iMjAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjIwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzBEOEZEQiI+PC9yZWN0Pjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjEwMCIgeT0iMTAwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojZmZmO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjEzcHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+MjAweDIwMDwvdGV4dD48L3N2Zz4=">
                        <h4>Label</h4>
                        <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
                        <img data-src="holder.js/200x200/auto/vine" class="img-responsive" alt="200x200" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyMDAiIGhlaWdodD0iMjAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iMjAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjIwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzM5REJBQyI+PC9yZWN0Pjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjEwMCIgeT0iMTAwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojMUUyOTJDO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjEzcHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+MjAweDIwMDwvdGV4dD48L3N2Zz4=">
                        <h4>Label</h4>
                        <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
                        <img data-src="holder.js/200x200/auto/sky" class="img-responsive" alt="200x200" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyMDAiIGhlaWdodD0iMjAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iMjAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjIwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzBEOEZEQiI+PC9yZWN0Pjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjEwMCIgeT0iMTAwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojZmZmO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjEzcHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+MjAweDIwMDwvdGV4dD48L3N2Zz4=">
                        <h4>Label</h4>
                        <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
                        <img data-src="holder.js/200x200/auto/vine" class="img-responsive" alt="200x200" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyMDAiIGhlaWdodD0iMjAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iMjAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjIwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzM5REJBQyI+PC9yZWN0Pjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjEwMCIgeT0iMTAwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojMUUyOTJDO2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjEzcHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+MjAweDIwMDwvdGV4dD48L3N2Zz4=">
                        <h4>Label</h4>
                        <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <h2 class="sub-header">Section title</h2>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Header</th>
                                <th>Header</th>
                                <th>Header</th>
                                <th>Header</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1,001</td>
                                <td>Lorem</td>
                                <td>ipsum</td>
                                <td>dolor</td>
                                <td>sit</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1,002</td>
                                <td>amet</td>
                                <td>consectetur</td>
                                <td>adipiscing</td>
                                <td>elit</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1,003</td>
                                <td>Integer</td>
                                <td>nec</td>
                                <td>odio</td>
                                <td>Praesent</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1,003</td>
                                <td>libero</td>
                                <td>Sed</td>
                                <td>cursus</td>
                                <td>ante</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1,004</td>
                                <td>dapibus</td>
                                <td>diam</td>
                                <td>Sed</td>
                                <td>nisi</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1,005</td>
                                <td>Nulla</td>
                                <td>quis</td>
                                <td>sem</td>
                                <td>at</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1,006</td>
                                <td>nibh</td>
                                <td>elementum</td>
                                <td>imperdiet</td>
                                <td>Duis</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1,007</td>
                                <td>sagittis</td>
                                <td>ipsum</td>
                                <td>Praesent</td>
                                <td>mauris</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1,008</td>
                                <td>Fusce</td>
                                <td>nec</td>
                                <td>tellus</td>
                                <td>sed</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1,009</td>
                                <td>augue</td>
                                <td>semper</td>
                                <td>porta</td>
                                <td>Mauris</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1,010</td>
                                <td>massa</td>
                                <td>Vestibulum</td>
                                <td>lacinia</td>
                                <td>arcu</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1,011</td>
                                <td>eget</td>
                                <td>nulla</td>
                                <td>Class</td>
                                <td>aptent</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1,012</td>
                                <td>taciti</td>
                                <td>sociosqu</td>
                                <td>ad</td>
                                <td>litora</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1,013</td>
                                <td>torquent</td>
                                <td>per</td>
                                <td>conubia</td>
                                <td>nostra</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1,014</td>
                                <td>per</td>
                                <td>inceptos</td>
                                <td>himenaeos</td>
                                <td>Curabitur</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1,015</td>
                                <td>sodales</td>
                                <td>ligula</td>
                                <td>in</td>
                                <td>libero</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the problem now. You just need to remove the offset classes because an offset is done by increasing the margin which in return increases the element's width and renders the total width of both the sidebar and the dashboard bigger than the total width and thus being pushed down.

Change this:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
```

To this:

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10 main">
```

Here is a [working demo](http://www.bootply.com/64A9ljTl4b) with the fix.

Comment: I guess I didn't get what exactly you meant by misalignment then. If you elaborate more or provide a screenshot pointing where the misalignment is. I might be able to help.

Comment: i meant that the `<div>` containing the sidebar is not at the same level than the `<div>` containing the main. The dashboard which  contains the dashboard should appear beside the sidebar and not below the sidebar. it is clearly seen in the Bootply example.

Comment: Please check the answer and let me know if that works for you.